# Run Eclipse project which contains IApplication from another project

Tags: java, eclipse, project, equinox, eclipse-kepler

I have an Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2) workspace with several projects which can be divided into two parts. The first part contains all projects except one.

They depend on each other and one of these projects is the prior entry point for execution. Let's call it "project A".

Now I created "project B" which forms the second part. I need to start project A from project B, get some calculation results from it and do some further work on these results (including user input and manipulation of files).

Since project A is an IApplication I have no idea how to start it. (It doesn't contain a main method, just a XMLFile with "some" parameters is contained in the project.)

At first I created a normal Eclipse project and added project A as dependency, which allowed me to instantiate the needed class from project A, but I am not able to run the `public Object start(IApplicationContext context)` method since it needs an IApplicationContext. Intuitive I tried to include the necessary class and create a context on my own.

After recognizing that this approach won't work, I searched around for Information about the IApplication(Context) and now I assume that these classes are only available in Eclipse-Plugin Development.

Since I never created an Eclipse-PlugIn I am not sure if it would be capable to fulfill all my described needs. Moreover I tried to create an test plugin with [this](http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2012/02/creating-headless-application.html) tutorial but I am failing at the point of "Launch an Eclipse Application" right inside the first instruction.

So, can anyone give me an advice on starting the IApplication?

In case it matters here is an extract of the XML configuration file I mentioned earlier. It is called `"ClassIWantToStart".launch`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.pde.ui.EquinoxLauncher">
<booleanAttribute key="append.args" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="automaticAdd" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="automaticValidate" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="bootstrap" value=""/>
...
</launchConfiguration>
```

It also contains StringAttributes like `target_bundles` and `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS` which contain an enormous number of attributes.

PS: project A seems to be an Eclipse-PlugIn itself

I am thankful for every advice.

Comment: If it uses `IApplication` it is an Eclipse Rich Client Program (RCP) which has to be run as a standalone program

Comment: There is no possibility of starting it from another project?

Comment: You could run it as a separate program but that probably doesn't help you. If the RCP is made up of plugins you may be able to use the plugins separately from the RCP. Or you may be able to write new plugins to add to the RCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reversing the dependencies. Now the RCP loads all the plugins.